# How to reset paint area in OnPaint call

Tags: c#, winforms, button

I'm trying to create a semi-transparent user control button whose background opacity changes from 30% black to 70% black on mouseEnter. I can successfully paint the button 30% black but I can't go from 70% to 30%. It's as if every time OnPaint() is called, it paints over what was already there instead of starting from scratch. I use a subclassed Panel as the user control's background.

Here's my OnPaint method for the subclassed Panel:

```
        Graphics g = e.Graphics;

        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, this.Width, this.Height);
        Brush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(Alpha, Color.Black)); // alpha is set by me

        g.FillRectangle(brush, rect);

        g.Dispose();
```

I've played with g.Clear() and g.Restore() but haven't had any luck. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: How are you calling `OnPaint()`?

Comment: I'm using Invalidate() to trigger OnPaint()

Comment: You're not going to get transparency to work like you want it to in WinForms.

Comment: It looks like you using the Graphics instance passed in to you in the OnPaint method.  You should not dispose this object since you didn't create it.

Comment: @CodyGray - yeah it's a mess. I hacked around this by swapping pre-made background images in and out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this by swapping 30% opaque black and 70% opaque black assets for the background image. I also set the button's BackColor to Color.Transparent.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how Windows handles transparency in that case. You should try invalidating the rectangle on the window *below* your window, if that window is repainted, the background might look just like you want.

Comment: I tried this but it seemed to cause an endless loop of OnPaint calls. I think Parent.Invalidate then called OnPaint of my control.

Comment: Parent.Invalidate will obviously trigger a paint in the child window. I didn't mean invalidating the parent, but rather the window behind your window (which can belong to another application).